# how would I iterate through these sets and display all the common numbers within them?

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, nested, set

```
spring =  {'April': {11,10,9,10,15,15,9,7,7,8,9,8,4,2,-1,-3,4,4,2,8,14,8,4,2,2,4,4,5,10,11,14}, 'May': {15,14,20,22,22,25,15,19,19,22,20,19,10,11,15,9,8,6,20,22,22,20,19,20,19,20,20,20,19,19,17}

summer = {'July':{26,27,24,25,25,27,28,26,28,23,20,22,34,25,8,9,17,22,23,25,20,26,23,14,24,27,28,23,25,23,20}, 'August':{8,9,15,25,20,21,24,18,22,25,25,24,26,37,20,20,23,23,27,19,17,22,26,29,24,22,24,28,24,25,23,23}

temp_data = {'spring': spring, 'summer': summer}
```

so what I need to do here is pretty much go through the dictionary and access the sets within the months (which I have already done), what I can't figure out how to do is check within each of the months in the season for the intersection points...

```
    for d,v in temp_data.items():
        print(d)
        #new = []
        for value in v:
            temps = v[value]
            combine = v[value].intersection(value)
            print(f'{value}: {temps}')
        print(combine)
```

I'm expecting an output of:

```
spring: [number , number, number, number]

summer: [number, number, number]
```

So it should return a list of all the numbers similar between the months of that specific season...

Please don't just give an answer with no explanation I am a beginner to python and trying to learn :),thank you

Comment: `spring: [number , number, number, number]`: `print(f"spring: [{', '.join('number' for _ in range(4))}]")`, that was easy. Now why don't you tell us the output you actually expect instead of being vague..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so, you haven't told me what your problem is, so I'm assuming that you're getting a syntax error (line 1). This is due to unbalanced parentheses - You're missing a parenthese (`}`) at the end of the line. Same goes for the second line (where you define 'summer). I ran the program after adding these brackets and it seemed to run fine.

I've just taken another look at the output and what you're expecting and figured out what your problem is. When you do `v[value].intersection(value)` that's just getting the intersection of the 'month' set and the name of the month - which is going to be a blank set. Instead, I would do something like this:

```
for d, v in temp_data.items():
    print(d)
    for value in v:
        temps = v[value]
        print(f'{value}: {temps}')
    combine = set.intersection(*v.values())
    print(combine)
```

Where the `for` loop is used to print out the individual months, then I use tuple unpacking (`*`) to get all the sets from the dictionaries' values. This means you can have more than two sets in the dictionary without adding to the complexity of your code.

Comment: so the code runs fine but when I print combine im expecting the numbers in the season spring the are similar to be outputted as a list, so lets say spring = 'May': {1,2,3,4}, 'January': {1,3,5} I expect the output: spring: [1,3] because those are the only common numbers in the season spring... instead my code is just outputting set()

Comment: @NickAreekadan I've just updated the response - I'm sorry, I hadn't properly read through the output, so I didn't notice that happening. My bad :)

Comment: wow.. that executed perfectly, thank you! I just have one question is there anyway you can explain why you used tuple unpacking a little clearer? I don't quite understand how or why it was used:)

Comment: @NickAreekadan Essentially, the ```set.intersection()``` method can combine many sets like so: ```set.intersection(setA, setB, setC...setZ)```, unlike the ```setA().intersection(setB())``` way of doing it, which will only work for 2 sets. Using the ```*``` unpacks the list of sets (which starts off like, say ```[{2, 4, 5, 10}, {2, 5, 10, 15}, {1, 2, 15, 17}]```) to use them as arguments for the method, like so: ```set.inersection({2, 4, 5, 10}, {2, 5, 10, 15}, {1, 2, 10, 17})``` which would return ```{2, 10}```.